# WebView Appears blank in Xcode

Tags: xcode, webview, load

Hey everyone I have this code that always worked for loading urls until I updated it to ios 8.4 Now when I click on the view a blank screen appears. Please help

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (unsafe_unretained,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIWebView *viewWeb;


@end
```

and

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *fullurl= @"http://www.google.com";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullurl];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_viewWeb loadRequest:requestObj];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: why is your UIWebView "unsafe_unretained"? Could that be the issue here?

Comment: I tried changing it to weak but still the result was the same

Comment: Please try with strong, unless you really need it to be weak.